# Output filter html_options in Smarty

Tags: smarty

I want to use string_format to format the output when generating html options with html_options.

For example, I'm trying to get options with a leading zero:

```
<select>
{$options=range(1,12)}
{html_options values=$options output=$options|string_format:'%02d'}
{/select}
```

This gives 01 as expected for the first option, but blank labels for the rest.  This ought to work based on the example on [this page](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.html.options.tpl) (search for 'truncate' on that page), so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow the smarty method `string_format` won't work on an array. What you can do though is create an associative array beforehand:

```
{section name=foo start=1 loop=13}
    {$options[$smarty.section.foo.index]=$smarty.section.foo.index|string_format:'%02d'}
{/section}
```

And simly use it as `options` instead of `values` and `output`:

```
<select>
    {html_options options=$options}
</select>
```